# Splashscreen runs in background

Tags: java, splash-screen

i got a problem with my SplashScreen not showing up, but running in the background..

Heres my Code, taken from [this](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-splash-screen-with-progress-bar-1) tutorial (hope it ok to post the link?!?) :

SplashScreen Class:

```
public final class SplashScreen extends JWindow {


BorderLayout borderLayout1 = new BorderLayout();
  JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
  JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
  FlowLayout southPanelFlowLayout = new FlowLayout();
  JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
  ImageIcon imageIcon;

  public SplashScreen(ImageIcon imageIcon) {
    this.imageIcon = imageIcon;
    try {
      jbInit();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
    }
  }

  // note - this class created with JBuilder
  void jbInit() throws Exception {
    imageLabel.setIcon(imageIcon);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(borderLayout1);
    southPanel.setLayout(southPanelFlowLayout);
    southPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    this.getContentPane().add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.getContentPane().add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    southPanel.add(progressBar, null);
    this.pack();
  }

  public void setProgressMax(int maxProgress)
  {
    progressBar.setMaximum(maxProgress);
  }

  public void setProgress(int progress)
  {
    final int theProgress = progress;
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        progressBar.setValue(theProgress);
      }
    });
  }

  public void setProgress(String message, int progress)
  {
    final int theProgress = progress;
    final String theMessage = message;
    setProgress(progress);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        progressBar.setValue(theProgress);
        setMessage(theMessage);
      }
    });
  }

  public void setScreenVisible(boolean b)
  {
    final boolean boo = b;
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        setVisible(boo);
      }
    });
  }

  private void setMessage(String message)
  {
    if (message==null)
    {
      message = "";
      progressBar.setStringPainted(false);
    }
    else
    {
      progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
    }
    progressBar.setString(message);
  }
}
```

In my Main() I start the SplashScren like this:

```
SplashScreen initscreen;
ImageIcon myImage = new ImageIcon(FilterConfiguratorJFrame.class.getResource("/images/logo.png"));
initscreen = new SplashScreen(myImage);
initscreen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
initscreen.setProgressMax(100);
initscreen.setScreenVisible(true);
```

Then I set the progress like this:

```
initscreen.setProgress("...loading Projects" , 40);
```

Then my program is loading Projects via a VPN from a Server at work.

Till here i dont get any errors, but the SplashScreen isn't showing up...

I have a OptionPane showing up when theres no connection to the server, and when THIS OptionPane is showing up the SplashScreen does to. When i click "OK" on the OptionPane it disappears, and so does the SplashScreen...

I tried it, and the SplashScreen shows up no matter when or where i let an OptionPane show...

**So my Question is, how do i force the SplashScreen into the foreground?**

I want the SplashScreen to show up on startup and updating its progressbar while different data ist loaded from the Database (which can last 1-2 minutes).

EDIT: Tried to force the SplashScreen to show by showinf a JFrame, doesn' work, seems like ist only working with OptionPanes.

Comment: 1) There is a SplashScreen class in the API which can be shown before the virtual machine is fully launched and which allows to show progress as well (see [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)) 2) Are you certain you are not blocking the EDT during the loading of your projects over VPN ?

Comment: 1)Just tried your example real quick... It works, a smal empty window is schowing up in the upper ledt corner, but thats not what i want. I want a picture showinf up an a progressBar. 2) blocking EDT? What dows that mean? How can i prevent that?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: Sry, this doesn't help me. My SplashScren works, it is only not showing... i create and show the SplashScreen before I start to load data from Database.